# How to parse arguments shell-check compliant, using a contained function, instead of script?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, arguments

### Context

I'm trying to write a decent bash parser using separate files and functions for:

- argument parsing (e.g. determining what to do)
- parsed argument processing (e.g. doing those things)
- printing the CLI usage.

However, when I try to pass the "POSITIONAL_ARGS" into the `parse_args() {`, the arguments don't seem to arrive.

### Example:

Suppose I have the following `main.sh` file in directory: `/src`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

POSITIONAL_ARGS=()
# source arg_parser.sh
source src/arg_parser/arg_parser.sh
source src/arg_parser/print_usage.sh

# print the usage if no arguments are given
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { print_usage; exit 1; }
echo "POSITIONAL_ARGS=$POSITIONAL_ARGS"
parse_args "$POSITIONAL_ARGS"
```

And the following `arg_parser.sh` file in: `src/arg_parser/arg_parser.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

parse_args() {
  local positional_args="$1"

  # Specify default argument values.
  local apply_certs_flag='false'
  local check_http_flag='false'
  local check_https_flag='false'
  local generate_certs_flag='false'
  local project_name_flag='false'
  local port_flag='false'


  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo "dollar1=$1"
    echo "positional_args=$positional_args"
    echo "dollar hashtag=$#"
    case $1 in
      -a|--apply-certs)
        apply_certs_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -ch|--check-http)
        check_http_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -cs|--check-https)
        check_https_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -g|--generate-certs)
        generate_certs_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -n|--project-name)
        project_name_flag='true'
        project_name="$2"
        assert_is_non_empty_string "${project_name}"
        shift # past argument
        shift
        ;;
      -p|--port)
        port_flag='true'
        port="$2"
        assert_is_non_empty_string "${project_name}"
        shift # past argument
        shift
        ;;
      -*)
        echo "Unknown option $1"
        print_usage
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done

  set -- "${POSITIONAL_ARGS[@]}" # restore positional parameters
}
```

### Expected output

When I run `./src/main.sh -a`, I would expect the output:

```bash
echo "POSITIONAL_ARGS=-a
dollar1=-a
positional_args=-a
dollar_hashtag=1

dollar1=-a
positional_args=-a
dollar_hashtag=0
```

### Output

However, instead of parsing/eating/shifting the arguments, the actual output is an infinite loop:

```
dollar1=
positional_args=
dollar hashtag=1
dollar1=
positional_args=
dollar hashtag=1
dollar1=
positional_args=
dollar hashtag=1
.... etc.
```

### Question

How could I pass the arguments from the CLI from `src/main.sh` into the `parse_args()` function in the file `src/arg_parser/arg_parser.sh` such that they can be parsed?

### Notes

I used to have

```
 -p|--prereq)
      prerequistes_only_flag='true'
      shift # past argument
      ;;
    -*|--*)
      echo "Unknown option $1"
      print_usage
      exit 1
      ;;
    *)
      POSITIONAL_ARGS+=("$1") # save positional arg
      shift # past argument
      ;;
  esac
```

however, shellcheck says the `--*)` will never be reached because of the `-*|`.

### Hypothesis

I think at least one error may be that I, in the original question, treated `POSITIONAL_ARGS` as a string instead of an array. However, shellcheck tells me it is an array:

```bash
In src/main.sh line 26:
echo "POSITIONAL_ARGS=$POSITIONAL_ARGS"
                      ^--------------^ SC2128 (warning): Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue(s)

- I thought `POSITIONAL_ARGS` contained the positional arguments.
- I treated `POSITIONAL_ARGS` as a variable instead of an array.

### Missing Information:

- `$@` gave the incoming arguments as an array.
- `$#` gave the length/number of the incoming arguments.

### Solution

A solution was found for the following `src/main.sh` content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source src/arg_parser/arg_parser.sh
source src/arg_parser/process_args.sh
source src/arg_parser/print_usage.sh


# print the usage if no arguments are given
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { print_usage; exit 1; }

parse_args "$@"

say_hello() {
  echo "Done parsing args. Hello world."
}
say_hello
```

and the accompanying `src/arg_parser/arg_parser.sh` filecontent:

```
#!/bin/bash

parse_args() {
  # local positional_args=("$@")

  # Specify default argument values.
  local apply_certs_flag='false'
  local check_http_flag='false'
  local check_https_flag='false'
  local generate_certs_flag='false'
  local project_name_flag='false'
  local port_flag='false'

  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  # while [[ "${#positional_args[@]}" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
      -a|--apply-certs)
        apply_certs_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -ch|--check-http)
        check_http_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -cs|--check-https)
        check_https_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -g|--generate-certs)
        generate_certs_flag='true'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -n|--project-name)
        project_name_flag='true'
        project_name="$2"
        assert_is_non_empty_string "${project_name}"
        shift # past argument
        shift
        ;;
      -p|--port)
        port_flag='true'
        port="$2"
        assert_is_non_empty_string "${project_name}"
        shift # past argument
        shift
        ;;
      -*)
        echo "Unknown option $1"
        print_usage
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done

  echo "apply_certs_flag=$apply_certs_flag"

}
```

### Room for improvements

One can see that I removed the use of `positional_args` and instead used the implicit array `$@` and array length `$#`. I think this solution could be improved a bit by swapping the `$@` with `positional_args` to make it more human readable. One issue in this swap is that the `shift` commands eat away the first element in the incoming array `$@`, and not from the `local positional_args` array.

So to resolve this issue, one could change the `shift` arguments to eat the first element in the `local positional_args` array. I did not yet figure out how to do that.